# Where there is option to bring vertical divider in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to show the divider for every labels is there any option in Bootstrap to show the vertical divider or in css like the below image.
[image]

Comment: Add what you have tried?

Comment: I tried for border-right property.

Comment: Add Related CSS and HTML with your question or create fiddle

Comment: try this <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="border-right: 1px dashed #333;  padding-right: 0px;"> .. Change the type of border.

Answer (score 1):

`Vertical Dividers` have been dropped in Bootstrap 3. [See here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9501)

You'll have to code on your own

or you can add this code to your style-sheet

```
.navbar .divider-vertical {
height: 40px;
margin: 0 9px;
border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, gray, transparent) 1 100%;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4tyw940u/)